# How to update Z fields with BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CHANGE parameter EXTENSION2?

Tags: abap, bapi

How to update Z fields with `BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CHANGE` using `EXTENSION2`?

I tried to update some Z fields in `LIKP` table using the BAPI to update deliveries but after call it any changes wasn't made.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the BAdI - SMOD_V50B0001. I made an enhancement implementaction and in the method EXIT_SAPLV50I_010 (User Exit BAPI for Changes to Outbound Delivery) set the follow code.

```
METHOD if_ex_smod_v50b0001~exit_saplv50i_010.

CONSTANTS: lc_vbkok    TYPE char5  VALUE 'VBKOK',           "Enhance the structure for more z fields in LIKP
           lc_vbpok    TYPE char5  VALUE 'VBPOK',           "Enhance the structure for more z fields in LIPS
           lc_cs_vbkok TYPE char8  VALUE 'CS_VBKOK'.

DATA: lv_item TYPE posnr_vl.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lfs_fieldname> TYPE any.

LOOP AT extension2 INTO DATA(lw_extension2).

  CASE lw_extension2-param.
      "As a structure in row 0
    WHEN lc_vbkok. "Fields for LIKP
        ASSIGN (lc_cs_vbkok) TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_vbkok>).
        IF <lfs_vbkok> IS ASSIGNED.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT lw_extension2-field OF STRUCTURE <lfs_vbkok> TO <lfs_fieldname>.
          IF <lfs_fieldname> IS ASSIGNED.
            <lfs_fieldname> = lw_extension2-value.
          ENDIF.
        ENDIF.

      "As a table from row 1 to n
    WHEN lc_vbpok. "Fields for LIPS
        MOVE lw_extension2-row TO lv_item.
        READ TABLE ct_vbpok ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_vbpok>) WITH KEY posnr_vl = lv_item.
        IF sy-subrc = 0.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT lw_extension2-field OF STRUCTURE <lfs_vbpok> TO <lfs_fieldname>.
          IF <lfs_fieldname> IS ASSIGNED.
            <lfs_fieldname> = lw_extension2-value.
          ENDIF.
        ENDIF.

  ENDCASE.

ENDLOOP.

ENDMETHOD.
```

Enhace the structures VBKOK as well LIKP with appen structures to add new z fields and enhance the structure VBPOK as well LIPS for the same purpose.

Also take a look to the program LV50LF01 and would need to implement an additional enhancement point to keep the values.

After this a think that I got it.

```
METHOD m_update_delivery.

DATA: lw_header_data    TYPE bapiobdlvhdrchg,
      lw_header_control TYPE bapiobdlvhdrctrlchg,
      lw_extension2     TYPE bapiext.

DATA: li_extension2 TYPE TABLE OF bapiext,
      li_return     TYPE TABLE OF bapiret2.

DATA: lv_delivery TYPE bapiobdlvhdrchg-deliv_numb.

lw_header_data-deliv_numb = p_w_output-delivery.
lw_header_control-deliv_numb = p_w_output-delivery.
lv_delivery = p_w_output-delivery.

lw_extension2-param = 'VBKOK'.
lw_extension2-field = 'ZZEXIDV'.

lw_extension2-value = p_w_output-value.
APPEND lw_extension2 TO li_extension2.

" Call BAPI to update delivery
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CHANGE'
  EXPORTING
    header_data    = lw_header_data
    header_control = lw_header_control
    delivery       = lv_delivery
  TABLES
    extension2     = li_extension2
    return         = li_return.

READ TABLE li_return INTO DATA(lw_return)
                     WITH KEY type = c_e.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  COMMIT WORK AND WAIT.
ENDIF.

ENDMETHOD.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **BAPI_COMMIT** after your BAPI function module.